# SharpDX: Creating TextureCube from set of images

Tags: direct3d, sharpdx, direct3d11

So I have 6 seperate images and I would like to build a textureCube out of them. What's the best way to go about it? Right now this is what I have, but I'm getting a memory access violation when the TextureCube tries to create itself.

```
SharpDX.DataBox[] textureData = new SharpDX.DataBox[6];
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    Texture2D tex = Texture2D.Load(device, resources[i].Filepath);
    SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D staged = (SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D)tex.ToStaging();
    textureData[i] = new SharpDX.DataBox(staged.NativePointer, staged.Description.Width, 0);
}

SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.TextureCube cube = SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.TextureCube.New(
            device,
            2048,
            PixelFormat.R8G8B8A8.UNorm,
            textureData);
```

The texture load is working fine. I can load the texture and then create a textureCube from a single image no problem. That's not much use though. When I try to create a cube using the raw data from my 6 separate images I'm getting the memory exception.

```
Result Message: 
Test method ResourceLoadingTests.LoadCubemapAndSave threw exception: 
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
Result StackTrace:  
at SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateTexture2D(Texture2DDescription& descRef, DataBox[] initialDataRef, Texture2D texture2DOut)
at SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D..ctor(Device device, Texture2DDescription description, DataBox[] data)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.Texture2DBase..ctor(GraphicsDevice device, Texture2DDescription description2D, DataBox[] dataBoxes)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.TextureCube..ctor(GraphicsDevice device, Texture2DDescription description2D, DataBox[] dataBoxes)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.TextureCube.New(GraphicsDevice device, Int32 size, PixelFormat format, DataBox[] textureData, TextureFlags flags, ResourceUsage usage)
```

Comment: Are the textures you are loading all 2048*2048 in size? Since you have this hardcoded....

Comment: Yep, the textures are 2048 for now. I'll downsize eventually but right now I just wanted to stick with the known values.

Comment: Ok, If you create your cube texture as render target it's easy to fill data with slices (and avoids staging roundtrip)